# (Python) slicing a list in reverse direction can not get first element

Tags: python, list, slice, reverse

I think the design of slice seems strange in logic

```
a =  [0,1,2,3,4]
# slice along forward direction
b = a[3:4:1] # ok it gives [3]
c = a[3:5:1] # ok it gives [3,4]
d = a[3:6:1] # ok it gives [3,4] , even exceed the upper bound 
# slice along reverse direction
b = a[4:1:-1]  # ok it gives [4,3,2]
c = a[4:0:-1]  # ok it gives [4,3,2,1]
d = a[4:-1:-1]  # it gives [] not expected [4,3,2,1,0]
e = a[4:-2:-1]  # it gives [4] not expected [4,3,2,1,0]
```

This means we can not include the fist element by slicing along reverse direction.
Even I think it is difficult to understand that the forward and reverse slicing do not follow same logic.

How do you think? Thanks for your comment.

===============

Thanks for your below comment

If a list can be seen as a circular linked object
and the index -1 indicates the last element

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
# the index will be
0,1,2,3,4
# or
-5,-4-3,-2-1
# a[-5]
0 # as expected
# when I slice 
a[4:-1:-1]  # it should give element with index start=4,3,2,1,end =0 , step=-1
# the expected results 
a[4],a[3],a[2],a[1],a[0]
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this to understand what is happening here.

```
print(a[4] == a[-1]) #True
print(a[3] == a[-2]) #True
```

Here, `a[4:-1:-1]` is similar to `a[4:4-1]`
If the ending index of the slice is equal to or less than the beginning index, it returns no item `[]`.
And, `a[4:-2:-1]` means `a[4:3:-1]`. That's why output is `[4]`

Comment: a[4:-1:-1] is not equal to [a[4], a[3],a[2],a[1],a[0]]  ?

Comment: No, -1 means the first number from the end. 
For that case, it needs to be like this `a[-1:-6:-1]`

Comment: Thank you,  I need to  study more

Answer (score 1):

Slicing always follows this logic `[start:stop:step]`.

You can omit values in a slice.

From last to third (excluded) in reverse:

```
a[:2:-1]
```

equivalent to:

```
a[4:2:-1]
```

output: `[4, 3]`

classical reverse:

```
a[::-1]
```

equivalent to:

```
a[-1::-1]
```

output: `[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`

Comment: # when I slice 
a[4:-1:-1]  # it should give element with index start=4,3,2,1,end =0 , step=-1
# the expected results 
a[4],a[3],a[2],a[1],a[0]    different with a[4:-1:-1]

Answer (score 1):

Start thinking it as a circular linked list with indexing you will get the concept.

-1 index is your last element and 0 is your first.